# WPF: A call to PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, .net-4.0, calling-convention

I'm encountering this error while using one of method in my .dll reference. 
When I call `MyRef.SetDbaseId` method I'm returned to VS with this error. I've tried to add `CallingConvention` enum parameters, but all of them does not work for me. I've also opened dll in DependencyWalker to check entry point and param (`ulong`), which fits in my app. It's confusing because other methods works fine. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?setdbaseid@@YGHK@Z")]
public static extern int SetDbaseID(ulong dbase_id);
```

```
ulong tmid = ulong.Parse(p_6);
i = MyRef.SetDbaseID(tmid);
```

Comment: Your declaration is wrong.  You make it impossible to guess exactly what you did wrong.  A long in native code is an int in C#.

Comment: If you have to use EntryPoint=?setdbaseid@@YGHK@Z, that means your dll  probably doesn't declare the exports with "extern C" declarations. From what I know, that's very hard to get right with dllimport. have you used dumpbin.exe /exports to check what the dll actually exports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mangled name, ?setdbaseid@@YGHK@Z, demangles to:

```
 int __stdcall setdbaseid(unsigned long);
```

Which makes your declaration wrong, an unsigned long in native code is 32-bits.  And the calling convention is wrong.  Fix:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", EntryPoint = "?setdbaseid@@YGHK@Z"))]
public static extern int SetDbaseID(uint dbase_id);
```

Comment: And presumably also change back to `stdcall` rather than `cdecl`.

Comment: @Hans Passant This worked for me! Could you tell me please how did you demangled this external method? Did you use any special tools?

Comment: I ran the undname.exe tool from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.